# How to have separated enabled modules in multisite based on Domain Access?

Tags: 7, domain-access

I have installed 'Domain Access' module to handle some sub-domains on a multisite installation based on Drupal 7.

This module share users, nodes and modules. But I want to have separated modules enabled on each sub-domain. But it seems if I enable a module it will be accessible on all the sub-domains.

Is the any way to bypass it? Sharing users and nodes are good points of this module and I need them but sharing modules ... no.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a year or two since I have used the [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) module on a site, but I don't think this is possible.

Domain Access runs all of the affiliate sites out of the same database, so there is a single `{system}` table, which is where all of the module info it.  Essentially, the module provides some content access rules based on domain (ie, [`node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7) based controls), along some helpers for other site-specific tasks and integration with other modules.  In the end, though, you still have a single database which means you have a single site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install them by hand (not using the back-office) inside the correct folder in "DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/mysubdomain.com/modules". Some tutorials mentionning the folder structure you should use: [here](https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) and [here](https://drupal.org/node/53705)

Comment: By using Domain Access module there is no separated folder for each sub-domain in /sites folder.

Comment: You need to create them manually. The point is that you need to tell Drupal which module to load depending on the domain used. This is a Drupal core functionnality, you do not need Domain to do that. You should look more into the first link: https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site